# Why is PS4 controller charging when not plugged in?

Tags: ps4

I've had my controller charging for a couple of hours, so I've unplugged it and according the the PS4 it's still charging. I've tried switching off the controller and PS4 and it still says it's charging.

Have I got drunk one night and invented a self-charging controller without remembering it?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Rebooting the console should probably fix it.

Comment: @Nolonar - nope - tried that

Comment: Funnily, when I turn the console off, the controller turns to the orange charging light

Comment: Hold down the PS button on the controller, and after 30 seconds it should shut itself off. Then turn it back on again. If the controller thinks it's charging, shutting off the console won't fully shut off the controller. This should do the trick

Comment: @Thebluefish Interestingly, it's now showing as a battery with a question mark. I suspect a damaged battery as the cable is fine with another controller.

Comment: Ya, controller sounds defective to me

Comment: This happened to my Wii U Pro Controller. A few days later the part you plug the cord into came out of place. See if you can open it up and make sure it's okay.

Comment: @CrabtasticGoat There's a definite fault. The touchpad presses itself intermittently which didn't happen before. I think it may be a case of going to controller heaven.

Comment: It happens... If you're willing to put the time in you could try to fix it. Here's a website for help! https://www.ifixit.com/Device/DualShock_4   Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the controller. Get a paperclip or something like that and insert its tip into the reset hole behind the controller. Press and hold the tiny reset button with the tip and try repairing the gamepad with the console.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with one of my controllers. It kept saying it was charging and stayed on while I shut the Playstation off with it. It wasn't a part failure since I had a spare backup piece and a new battery. So I plugged it into the wall via a USB cable and logged on with it. Next, I held down the PS button for about 30 seconds or so. I turned it on again and turned off the Playstation with the controller. Then I removed the USB cable and started the Playstation with the controller. After it was turned on, I plugged the controller back in with the USB cable. The controller was charging like normal and when I removed the cable the battery loading stopped as well.